# RxJava2: PublishProcessor callbacks for the first subscribed and the last unsubscribed observer

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I use a `PublishProcessor<?>` for serving multiple observers. Is there a way to know when the very first observer gets subscribed and the very last observer gets disposed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, you need to capture the subscribers and cancellers:

```
PublishProcessor<?> pp = ...

AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

Action onFirst = ...

Action onLast = ...

Flowable<?> f = pp.doOnSubscribe(s -> {
    if (counter.getAndIncrement() == 0) {
        onFirst.run();
    }
})
.doFinally(() -> {
    if (counter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
        onLast.run();
    }
})

// use f for subscribe() instead of pp
```